# Postgresql constraints SARG

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

Are SQL Server style [SARGs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799584/what-makes-a-sql-statement-sargable) relevant to PostgreSQL queries in general and more specifically on table constraints?

I have a parent table with many [inherited children](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html), partitioned by a date column.
Would it be better to change the constraints from

```
CHECK (date_part('year', end_of_dt)::integer = 2016)
```

to

```
CHECK (end_of_dt between '2016-01-01 0:00:00' and '2016-12-31 23:59:59.999')
```

Comment: I would also like to know what a SARG is, you should explain a bit about it in the question.

Comment: And also what "inherited" means. Do you use Postgres inheritance or something else? The scripts (CREATE TABLE) of the parent and a child table would be good additions, too, to make the question more clear.

Comment: or why that would matter even.. If they both return the same results we're essentially just talking about the speed of the check, no?

Answer (score 3):

We can easily test this.. but first, stop using `date_part`. Instead, use `extract`. It's the same thing with slightly different syntax, but it's standardized.

## Testing it

Let's create a table with all the second `TIMESTAMPS` for the year.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS (
  SELECT to_timestamp(x) AS ts
  FROM generate_series(
    extract(EPOCH FROM '2016-01-01'::timestamp)::int,
    extract(EPOCH FROM '2017-01-01'::timestamp)::int
  ) AS t(x)
);
```

Then we can implement your check in a WHERE condition to get a basic idea of speed. BTW, there are a ton more seconds in a year than I first though. There are 31,622,401 seconds in a year. It takes 1093 MB to load this sample data.

took, 12.6, 10.8, 11.0 seconds.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM foo
WHERE extract(YEAR FROM ts) = 2016;
```

took, 6.1, 6.3, 6.2 seconds

```
SELECT * FROM foo
WHERE ts BETWEEN '2016-01-01 0:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 23:59:59.999';
```

## Conclusion

Yes, the second is roughly 2x as fast in three trial runs. For the purposes of creating a check constraint, you should use the latter.

## Addendum

PostgreSQL has the ability to [add functional indexes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html), however an index on `date_part()` is not possible

```
CREATE INDEX onyear ON foo (date_part('year',ts));
ERROR:  functions in index expression must be marked IMMUTABLE
```

I assume this is because the result of datetime functions comes back in the client's timezone. Either way, this makes it even more advantageous to use the `timestamp` ranges. One easy to get more speed if need be would be with materialized views though..

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW matviewfoo AS
SELECT
  extract(YEAR FROM ts)::smallint AS year,
  ts
FROM foo;
CREATE INDEX yearidx ON matviewfoo (year);
VACUUM FULL matviewfoo;
```

Now you can

```
SELECT count(*) FROM matviewfoo WHERE year = 2016;
```

And, you're down to 4.1 seconds

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I've found empirically

```
CREATE TABLE accounts (
    account_id INT PRIMARY KEY
    ,eod DATE
    );

CREATE TABLE accounts_p2015 (LIKE accounts INCLUDING ALL) INHERITS (accounts);
CREATE TABLE accounts_p2016 (LIKE accounts INCLUDING ALL) INHERITS (accounts);
CREATE TABLE accounts_p2017 (LIKE accounts INCLUDING ALL) INHERITS (accounts);
```

So the question becomes performance of these constraints:

```
ALTER TABLE accounts_p2015 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_eod CHECK (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eod) = 2015);
ALTER TABLE accounts_p2016 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_eod CHECK (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eod) = 2016);
ALTER TABLE accounts_p2017 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_eod CHECK (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eod) = 2017);
```

vs

```
ALTER TABLE accounts_p2015 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_eod CHECK ( eod BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-12-31');
ALTER TABLE accounts_p2016 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_eod CHECK (eod BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31');
ALTER TABLE accounts_p2017 ADD CONSTRAINT chk_eod CHECK (eod BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31');
```

The first constraints (not SARGable) looks like it hits all child tables:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE eod = '2016-11-11';
                            QUERY PLAN                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Append  (cost=0.00..114.75 rows=34 width=8)
->  Seq Scan on accounts  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=8)
        Filter: (eod = '2016-11-11'::date)
->  Seq Scan on accounts_p2015  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=11 width=8)
        Filter: (eod = '2016-11-11'::date)
->  Seq Scan on accounts_p2016  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=11 width=8)
        Filter: (eod = '2016-11-11'::date)
->  Seq Scan on accounts_p2017  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=11 width=8)
        Filter: (eod = '2016-11-11'::date)
(9 rows)
```

And the second (SARGable) only hits the relevant child table:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT *
FROM accounts
WHERE eod = '2016-11-11';
                            QUERY PLAN                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Append  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=12 width=8)
->  Seq Scan on accounts  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=8)
        Filter: (eod = '2016-11-11'::date)
->  Seq Scan on accounts_p2016  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=11 width=8)
        Filter: (eod = '2016-11-11'::date)
(5 rows)
```

So I guess SARGs are relevant to PostgreSQL query and constraint optimization.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/99a4f/1/0)

Comment: +1 for the finding but if you are to use a not common term ("SARG"), it's better to define it - in the question. Many readers will guess that it has something to do with Sargeability but not all. The rest will wonder *"WTF is SARG?"*

Comment: For the first design, what happens if you add an index on `accounts (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eod))`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ you can't, extract/date_part are not immutable.

Comment: A functional index didn't change the query plan.
    Indexes:
    "accounts_p2017_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (account_id)
    "idx2" btree (date_part('year'::text, eod))

Comment: Yes, you'd have to add the redundant condition `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM eod) = 2016` in the query, to do the partition elimiation.